# URL rewriting Regex with capture group

Tags: .net, regex

I'm writing the following regular expression using .NET's regex engine:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"/Explorer/PeopleDirectory([/\?].*)?$");
var a = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/assets/images/logo.png", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$0");
var b = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$0");
var c = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$0");
var d = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory.aspx", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$0");
var e = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory?param1=value1&param2=value2", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$0");
var f = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/?param1=value1&param2=value2", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$0");
```

My desired output would be:

```
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=assets/images/logo.png
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=
No match (as-is)
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=?param1=value1&param2=value2
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Current output is:

```
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/assets/images/logo.png
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=/Explorer/PeopleDirectory
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=/Explorer/PeopleDirectory
No match (as-is)
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=/Explorer/PeopleDirectory?param1=value1&param2=value2
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Assume URL encoding of result later. How do I get rid of the /Explorer/PeopleDirectory/ from appearing in the output?

I thought I was only capturing the part that comes after the /Explorer/PeopleDirectory.... part so that when I reference it using $0 it would only capture the part in the parentheses? Could someone please explain where I've erred?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issues is :

you should use **$1** in your replace string , not **$0** :

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?i)/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/?((?!\.aspx).*)$");
var a = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/assets/images/logo.png", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1");
var b = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1");
var c = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1");
var d = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory.aspx", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1");
var e = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory?param1=value1&param2=value2", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1");
var f = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/?param1=value1&param2=value2", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1");
```

here are the replace result:

```
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=assets/images/logo.png
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory.aspx
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=?param1=value1&param2=value2
http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\/PeopleDirectory(?:/|))(.*)
```

with replace

```
/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$1
```

only 1 thing the .aspx will be used as a parameter you can exclude it in some way or i must exclude via regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this. this matches even if you have another extension than .aspx

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"/Explorer/PeopleDirectory([^/\?]*[/\?]*)(.*)$");
var a = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/assets/images/logo.png", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$2");
var b = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$2");
var c = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$2");
var d = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory.aspx", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$2");
var e1 = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory?param1=value1&param2=value2", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$2");
var f = reg.Replace(@"http://localhost:106/Explorer/PeopleDirectory/?param1=value1&param2=value2", "/Explorer/PeopleDirectoryProxy.aspx?pdurl=$2");
```